# A simple basis for the space of two variables homogenous polynomials of a fixed degree.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Denote by $\mathcal{P}_l$ the linear space of the complex-valued homogeneous polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of degree $l$. I read that polynomials of the form $(ax+by)^l$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ do span the space $\mathcal{P}_l$. Can anyone help why this is true?
Many thanks in advance.\

In the book I read this he gives an indication as follows : if we denote by $V_l$ the span of the $(ax+by)^l$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. Remark that since $V_l$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{P_l}\equiv \mathbb{C}^{l+1}$ it is a closed subspace and thus if $\gamma(t)$ is a smooth curve in $V_l$, the derivative $\gamma'(t)$ will also lie in $V_l$.

Comment: you can edit your original post to clarify

Comment: Have you tried $(x+\zeta^ky)^l$ for $k=0,\dots,l-1$ and $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/l}$?

Comment: @zag thank you.

Comment: @Somos. Thank you. Can I have a little bit more detail and where does the idea of the l-th root of unity come from  ?

Comment: In [multisection of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) note that a polynomial is a special case of power series.

Comment: @Somos. Thank you so much sir. Unfortunately still don't see how can we apply this to our two variables homogeneous polynomials. I'm stuck on it for days and It would be so appreciated if you can provide more details. thank you again for your time.

Comment: Well can you solve the problem for $l=2$ at least?

Comment: @Somos yes the $l=2$ case is simple. a simple identification of coefficients and complex square roots does the job.

Comment: Please show your work for $l=2$ in your question. Why would you need complex square roots?

Comment: @Somos you right, it can be done without using complex square roots : the space $\mathcal{P}_2$ can be spanned by $\{ x^2,(x+y)^2,(x-y)^2\}$ since combining these three polynomials we can get the different components $x^2, xy$ and $y^2$ constituting any homogeneous polynomial of second degree. But still dont see how to justify the ( now somehow clear) idea behind considering $l-th$ roots of unity. Another remark is that the space $\mathcal{P}_l$ is of dimension $l+1$ and cannot be spanned by the $(x+\zeta^k y)_{0\leq k \leq l-1}$ alone.

Comment: Please include your work in the question itself and not comments. You are right about the dimension, but you need to include $0$ along with the roots of unity.